# Highchart not fully rendered, only when mouse over

Tags: javascript, highcharts

im making a pie chart with a lot of data, however the chart its not fully rendered (only the half) the other half its rendered only when i pass the mouse over, and not always, here is my code!:

```
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts(
    {
        chart: 
        {
            type: 'pie',
            height: 1200,
            width:  1200
        },
        title: 
        {
            text: 'Films by category'
        },
        yAxis: 
        {
            title: 
            {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: 
        {
            pie: 
            {
                shadow: false,
                center: ['50%', '50%']
            }
        },
        tooltip: 
        {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        series: 
        [
            {
                name: 'Film cateories',
                data: browserData,
                size: '60%',
                dataLabels: 
                {
                    formatter: function() 
                    {
                        return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
                    },
                    color: 'white',
                    distance: -30
                }
            }, 
        {
            name: 'Films',
            data: versionsData,
            size: '80%',
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: 
            {
                formatter: function() 
                {
                    // display only if larger than 1
                    return this.y > 1 ? '<b>'+ this.point.name +':</b> '+ this.y +'%'  : null;
                }
            },
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point:
            {
                events:
                {
                    click: function()
                    {
                        alert("Value "+this.y+" category "+this.category+" id "+this.id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQ8k8/)

Comment: Make it a fiddle, so we can mess with the code.

Comment: Ready! sorry for the long data for security reasons i cant publish my data source!

Comment: At first look one would think it's simply way too much data for poor highcharts, but removing the data doesn't fix it. Maybe a bug in the code around..

Comment: You are right, its because im using highcharts.getOptions().colors and this array has only ten different colors and when im using the last color, the chart starts to repeat them.

Comment: Yeah that could be it, I removed categories and it started working good once there were <= 10.

Comment: It's done! i've come up with a little workaround for this problem, here it is:

      // Workaround for the lack of colors in Highcharts.getOptions().colors
        var colors = [];
        for(var i=0;i<categoriesJson.records.record.length;i++)
            if(i<Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length)
                colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]);
            else
                colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i-Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length]);

Basically im reapating the colors.

Comment: I cant answer my question until 8 hours :(

Comment: Your work-around seems to work for me. Nice work.