# Highchart donut pie - Is there a max number of slices

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Is there a max number of slices allowed in ("donut pie")? I have used the highchart ("donut pie") example and I cannot get past more than 10 slices. Notice inner slice 'F' is missing. Sample code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/600phuws/

```
$(function () {

var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    data = [{
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
            data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        y: 21.63,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Firefox versions',
            categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
            data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }, {
        y: 11.94,
        color: colors[2],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Chrome versions',
            categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
                'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'],
            data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
            color: colors[2]
        }
    }, {
        y: 7.15,
        color: colors[3],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[3]
        }
    }, {
        y: 2.14,
        color: colors[4],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Opera versions',
            categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
            data: [ 0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
            color: colors[4]
        }
    }, {
        y: 8.15,
        color: colors[5],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[5]
        }
    }, {
        y: 9.15,
        color: colors[6],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[6]
        }
    }, {
        y: 10.15,
        color: colors[7],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[7]
        }
    }, {
        y: 11.15,
        color: colors[8],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[8]
        }
    }, {
        y: 12.15,
        color: colors[9],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[9]
        }
    }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
                'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'],
            data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
            color: colors[10]
        }
    }, 
    ],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;


// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
        name: categories[i],
        y: data[i].y,
        color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
        brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
        versionsData.push({
            name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
            y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
            color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
        });
    }
}

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: 'white',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '80%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%'  : null;
            }
        }
    }]
});
});

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script> <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Sample Highchart - ["Donut Pie"](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/)

Comment: I see more than 10 slices.

Comment: The inner slice. Do you see slice 'F' drawn.

Comment: Oh, I see. It loads blank and then shows up when I hover over it.

Comment: Yes thats the issue. If you remove any elements from pie, then everything works fine until its more than 10.

Comment: Are you adjusting the totals so they come out to 100, even if more than 10?

Comment: Could be related to the fact that there are only 10 available colors. There's a [possible work-around here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983210/highchart-not-fully-rendered-only-when-mouse-over) (in the comments).

Comment: Thats not true. Highchart should compute by itself on % size of each slices. Add sample url from highchart in question body above.

Comment: It could be there are 10 colors. But where do I find this limit in their documentation. I do not want to guess. Otherwise I would look for some other pie chart then. 10 limit would be a bummer.

Comment: Just add your own color to the additional slice(s) to see if that was the restriction. Also, don't assume that it can calculate to an even 100. Try one with your own total to see.

Comment: Well I can certainly try that.

Comment: To output the number of colors, try `console.log(colors.length);`. Check out that [work-around from user2465233](http://jsfiddle.net/600phuws/1/) that repeats the colors. You could probably build your own custom list of colors, too.

Comment: @showdev, that looks promising :)

Comment: @showdev that was the issue. Can you please add the solution and I will accept it.

Comment: Great! I can't take credit. [user2465233](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2465233/user2465233) wrote that code and has [not yet posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983210/highchart-not-fully-rendered-only-when-mouse-over).

Comment: you can still point to his code in your response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Highchart has a limited list of available colors (only 10).

Another user ([user2465233](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465233/user2465233)) wrote a [work-around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983210/highchart-not-fully-rendered-only-when-mouse-over) that repeats those existing colors to create new colors for as many slices as you have in your chart.

```js
// Workaround for the lack of colors in Highcharts.getOptions().colors
// written by user2465233

var colors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    if (i < Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length) {
        colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]);
    } else {
        colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i - Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length]);
    }
}
```

```js
$(function() {

  var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

  // Workaround for the lack of colors in Highcharts.getOptions().colors
  var colors = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    if (i < Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length) {
      colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]);
    } else {
      colors.push(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i - Highcharts.getOptions().colors.length]);
    }
  }

  var data = [{
      y: 55.11,
      color: colors[0],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'MSIE versions',
        categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
        data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
        color: colors[0]
      }
    }, {
      y: 21.63,
      color: colors[1],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Firefox versions',
        categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
        data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43],
        color: colors[1]
      }
    }, {
      y: 11.94,
      color: colors[2],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Chrome versions',
        categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
          'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'
        ],
        data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22],
        color: colors[2]
      }
    }, {
      y: 7.15,
      color: colors[3],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[3]
      }
    }, {
      y: 2.14,
      color: colors[4],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Opera versions',
        categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
        data: [0.12, 0.37, 1.65],
        color: colors[4]
      }
    }, {
      y: 8.15,
      color: colors[5],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[5]
      }
    }, {
      y: 9.15,
      color: colors[6],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[6]
      }
    }, {
      y: 10.15,
      color: colors[7],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[7]
      }
    }, {
      y: 11.15,
      color: colors[8],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[8]
      }
    }, {
      y: 12.15,
      color: colors[9],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[9]
      }
    }, {
      y: 13.15,
      color: colors[10],
      drilldown: {
        name: 'Safari versions',
        categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
          'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
        ],
        data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14],
        color: colors[10]
      }
    }, ],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;






  // Build the data arrays
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
      name: categories[i],
      y: data[i].y,
      color: data[i].color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
      brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
      versionsData.push({
        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
      });
    }
  }

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Total percent market share'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        shadow: false,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Browsers',
      data: browserData,
      size: '60%',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
        },
        color: 'white',
        distance: -30
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Versions',
      data: versionsData,
      size: '80%',
      innerSize: '60%',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          // display only if larger than 1
          return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
        }
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Full credit, of course, goes to [user2465233](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2465233/user2465233). Since he/she has not been "seen" on StackOverflow since August 2013, I thought it was unlikely that he/she would return to post an answer.

---

### EDIT:

Here's another method that's a bit shorter. When assigning colors, I'm using a [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to map any slice number to the available HighChart colors.

```
var color_index = i>(colors.length-1) ? i%colors.length : i;
```

Given any slice number `i`, this generates a `color_index` that falls within the range of available colors. Then, use that `color_index` to reference the `colors` array generated by HighChart:

```
var this_color = colors[color_index];

// add browser data
browserData.push({
    name: categories[i],
    y: data[i].y,
    color: this_color
});

// add version data
drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
    brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
    versionsData.push({
        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: Highcharts.Color(this_color).brighten(brightness).get()
    });
}
```

In the snippet below, I've added a bunch of extra slices to demonstrate flexibility:

```js
$(function() {

  var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    data = [{
        y: 55.11,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'MSIE versions',
          categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
          data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81]
        }
      }, {
        y: 21.63,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Firefox versions',
          categories: ['Firefox 2.0', 'Firefox 3.0', 'Firefox 3.5', 'Firefox 3.6', 'Firefox 4.0'],
          data: [0.20, 0.83, 1.58, 13.12, 5.43]
        }
      }, {
        y: 11.94,
        color: colors[2],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Chrome versions',
          categories: ['Chrome 5.0', 'Chrome 6.0', 'Chrome 7.0', 'Chrome 8.0', 'Chrome 9.0',
            'Chrome 10.0', 'Chrome 11.0', 'Chrome 12.0'
          ],
          data: [0.12, 0.19, 0.12, 0.36, 0.32, 9.91, 0.50, 0.22]
        }
      }, {
        y: 7.15,
        color: colors[3],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 2.14,
        color: colors[4],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Opera versions',
          categories: ['Opera 9.x', 'Opera 10.x', 'Opera 11.x'],
          data: [0.12, 0.37, 1.65]
        }
      }, {
        y: 8.15,
        color: colors[5],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 9.15,
        color: colors[6],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 10.15,
        color: colors[7],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 11.15,
        color: colors[8],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 12.15,
        color: colors[9],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Safari versions',
          categories: ['Safari 5.0', 'Safari 4.0', 'Safari Win 5.0', 'Safari 4.1', 'Safari/Maxthon',
            'Safari 3.1', 'Safari 4.1'
          ],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23, 0.21, 0.20, 0.19, 0.14]
        }
      },

      // ADDITIONAL SLICES BELOW, FOR DEMOSTRATION PURPOSES

      {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      }, {
        y: 13.15,
        color: colors[10],
        drilldown: {
          name: 'Extra',
          categories: ['Extra 1', 'Extra 2', 'Extra 3'],
          data: [4.55, 1.42, 0.23]
        }
      },

      // END ADDITIONAL SLICES


    ],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;





  // Build the data arrays
  for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

    var color_index = i > (colors.length - 1) ? i % colors.length : i,
      this_color = colors[color_index];

    // add browser data
    browserData.push({
      name: categories[i],
      y: data[i].y,
      color: this_color
    });

    // add version data
    drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
    for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
      brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
      versionsData.push({
        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: Highcharts.Color(this_color).brighten(brightness).get()
      });
    }

  }

  // Create the chart
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Total percent market share'
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        shadow: false,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Browsers',
      data: browserData,
      size: '60%',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
        },
        color: 'white',
        distance: -30
      }
    }, {
      name: 'Versions',
      data: versionsData,
      size: '80%',
      innerSize: '60%',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter: function() {
          // display only if larger than 1
          return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
        }
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Vow! I am amazed by the details you have put in :)